# Oracle Form Builder: Switching between tabs in a form

Tags: sql, oracle, tabs, builder, oracleforms

i am building a form in oracle forms builder

i have a tabbed canvas

i need to know how to swap to the next tab when a button is pressed

so what do i program into the next-tab button??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best way normally is to navigate to an item on the new tab page, e.g.

> ```
> GO_ITEM('BLOCK_NAME.ITEM_NAME');
> ```

OR you can make the tab page topmost explicitly:

> ```
> SET_CANVAS_PROPERTY('CANVAS_NAME', TOPMOST_TAB_PAGE, 'TAB_PAGE_NAME');
> ```